# Phone gap 3.0 + sencha touch open urls in device browser

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sencha-touch

Am building an android app using sencha touch + phonegap 3.0, requirement to open some urls in external browser. For Ios am using    Ext.device.Device.openURL(url), and its working fine. But in android when i click on link, its open in my appview..

What i tried is

```
window.open(url, '_system', 'location=no'); // not worked still opens the in app view

window.open(alltaskurl,  '_blank', 'location=yes'); // not worked opens in app view
```

Then i installed InAppBrowser **phoneGap plugin** and tried 
changed my config.xml file

```
   <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
    </feature>

window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes'); // not worked as well
```

I dont know what to do with this, am spending a lot of time to solve this issue, please help me..thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this with the following code

```
 navigator.app.loadUrl(url, {openExternal: true});
```

I got it from one of the sencha forum

Comment: this approach only works for Android and not for iOS, so I'd recommend the cross-platform `window.open(url, '_system')` approach [from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19953383/1265240). Make sure you added the InAppBrowser plugin via `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`

Comment: window.open will crash the app(tested in sencha touch framework). So navigator.app.loadurl is correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Once you installed `InAppBrowser` use:

```
window.open(url, '_system');
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks Dibish.. you put me on the right track.
I'm using a library that does some of it's own href's so, to avoid messing with that library I did this instead:

```
window.onclick = clickEvent;

function clickEvent(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var t = e.target || e.srcElement
    if ( t.name || t.href ){
       if( typeof t.href == "string" && t.href.substr(0,4) == 'http' ){
           if( t.attributes.href.value !== "#" ){
               window.open(t.href, '_system', 'location=yes');
           }
           return false; // no further action for this click
       }
    }
    return true; // process click as normal
}
```

edit: used window.open() instead of Android specific navigator.app.loadUrl() .
I also had to weed out href="#" occurrences.